# MatDialogRef on close sending data to parent undefined Angular 13 with angular material 13

Tags: angular, angular-material

**Parent component**

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openCreateMetric() {
    this.dialog.open(MetricCreateComponent, {
      width: '50%',
      disableClose: true,
      autoFocus: 'dialog',
    });
    this.dialog.afterAllClosed.subscribe((closeTrigger) => {
      console.log(closeTrigger) --> Always undefined at the parent
      this.loadFlag.next(Math.random())
    });
  }
```

**Child component**

```
export class MetricCreateComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
    constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MetricCreateComponent>,
            @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public input: MetricDetailsDto) {   
        }
    
     onDialogCloseClick(): void {
            this.dialogRef.close({data: false})
        }
}
```

**Template**

```
  <button mat-icon-button tabindex="-1" (click)="onDialogCloseClick()">
      <i class="fal fa-times"></i>
  </button>
```

Always getting undefined at the parent console.log(closeTrigger)

Comment: Can you please add the template of your dialog component? I suspect you are using the `matDialogClose` directive and that one has a slightly different behavior (you need to put your result data there, in the template).

Comment: Is this the only close button you have for this modal? No modal actions at the bottom, like Save and Cancel ?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I am not using matDialogClose update the template. Please have a look

Comment: No I am closing on click of this button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using `afterClosed` instead of [`afterAllClosed`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialog). The latter is of type `Observable<void>`.

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MetricCreateComponent, {
  width: '50%',
  disableClose: true,
  autoFocus: 'dialog',
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((closeTrigger) => {
  console.log(closeTrigger);
  this.loadFlag.next(Math.random());
});
```

Comment: Getting an error as Property 'afterClosed' does not exist on type 'MatDialog'. I am using this import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

Comment: Yes, it is not a property that exists on the `MatDialog` service itself, but on the reference that you get by calling the `.open` method. Please check the updated answer

Comment: Your answer works but need to used function instead of property dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((closeTrigger) => {
      console.log(closeTrigger);
     
    });

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I updated the answer and added the missing parentheses.